# "clear" not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line

Whenever I try to enter the "clear" command in cmd, it returns the same message:

> "clear" not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It happens with some other command lines too, but this one is really annoying because I often need it. I have no idea how to fix it.

Any tips?

Comment: I believe "clear" is a UNIX command.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The message is completely correct; no such command exists.

Did you mean `cls`?

Answer (score 17):

This command, `clear` may exist in other code, but not in batch code.
If you mean the command need to clear the screen, use `cls`. That will clean the screen.

Answer (score 4):

**This will clear all the previously entered commands.**

For windows CMD use

```
cls
```

For Unix/MAC/Linux use

```
clear
```

Comment: most important is how do we know from bash which terminal did user use.
cmd/linux

Answer (score 0):

To clear the screen in powershell, use `clear` while in CMD, use `cls`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import system #for windows
clear = lambda: system('cls')
```

And then you can call the `clear()` func.